# How to control color in custom panel function?

Tags: r, lattice

In this plot, the grouping is indicated by the color.

```
xyplot(mpg ~ disp, data = mtcars,
   type = c('p', 'g'), auto.key = TRUE, 
   groups = cyl)
```

In the following plot, I would like to indicate the grouping via color as well, as in the example above.

```
xyplot(mpg ~ disp, data = mtcars, auto.key = TRUE,
   groups = cyl,
   panel = function(x, y, ...) {
     panel.xyplot(x, y, type = 'g', ...)
     panel.text(x, y, labels = mtcars$gear)
   })
```

Does anybody know how to achieve this? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks and best greetings,
Sebastian

Comment: You will be able to answer your own question. Just add it as an answer (and then accept it as correct) once the system lets you in.

Answer (score 1):

Do you just mean this (passing `col` to `panel.text`):

```
xyplot(mpg ~ disp, data = mtcars,
   groups = cyl,
   panel = function(x, y, ...) {
     panel.xyplot(x, y, type = 'g', ...)
     panel.text(x, y, labels = mtcars$gear, col = mtcars$gear)
   })
```

[image]

Comment: Hello Thomas, thanks! It would be nice to have a solution that works smoothly with the auto.key argument (I omitted this in the original example). This would work with some fiddling with the approach you suggested, but I am wondering, if there is a more straight-forward solution. Best greetings, Sebastian

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that satisfies me:

```
xyplot(mpg ~ disp, data = mtcars,
   groups = cyl, 
   auto.key = list(title = 'Cylinders'),
   panel = panel.superpose,
   panel.groups = function(x, y, col.symbol, ...) {
     panel.text(x, y, 
                labels = mtcars$gear, 
                col = col.symbol)
   })
```

I think I am getting a grasp of how grouping in lattice works ;-)

Thanks Thomas, and best greetings,
Sebastian